# Magento 1.9 How can i get and store configurable attributes like color,size,monogram based on product in custom page through custom table

Tags: magento-1.9

My requirement is to fetch all data of the product in cart apart from `SKU`, `name`, and `quantity`. 
Is there anyone to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Load cart items and change attribute name like color, size as per your requirement.

```
$productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

inside product loop

```
    foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
    //var_dump($product);
    var_dump($product->getData());
}
```

if you want only monogram attribute then change above line by

```
$productcollection->addAttributeToSelect('monogram'); //here monogram is an attribute code which will never change because it is not editable.
```

Comment: But through this how can I get monogram text and monogram options

Comment: I have edited my answer , may be it helps.